# Make Alexa speak the result of a request in Python

Tags: python, python-requests, alexa-skills-kit, lib

Please, someaone can help me?

I want Alexa to speak the result of the output of get_func ()
What is the correct way to pass the value on to her?

The output of get_func() is a integer.

### Here is my code

```py
class ConsultaTempIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Hello World Intent."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return ask_utils.is_intent_name("ConsultaTempIntent")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        #type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        response_builder = handler_input.response_builder
        logging.info("LaunchRequest was trigerred")

        slot = ask_sdk_core.utils.request_util.get_slot(handler_input, "TempAG")

        if slot.value:
            temp = get_func()
            speak_output = "The tempeture is {temp} degrees"

            return (
               handler_input.response_builder
              #      .speak(speak_output)
                # .ask("add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond")
                    .response
            )
```

Comment: https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-python-city-guide

Comment: https://chatbotslife.com/building-alexa-skills-in-python-for-absolute-beginners-8166a7ad01fa?gi=40baa80a6d5f

Answer (score 2):

You need to make `speak_output` an f-string (by adding an "f" before the first quote)…

```
speak_output = f"The tempeture is {temp} degrees"
```

Then you need to uncomment your `.speak` function call…

```
#      .speak(speak_output)
```

From what I can see, everything else should work.

*ps. it's spelled "temperature"*

Comment: Or adding `.format(temp=temp)` after the quote if you're using Python2… which you shouldn't be.